# What tells unity that a cursor is hovering over a button and how can Unity Netcode for Gameobjects affect it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-networking

What tells unity that a cursor is hovering over a button (how does it know when to highlight it or do something when a click happens and the cursor is on it). And how does the Unity Netcode for GameObjects affect it? I have a problem with my game that uses the Unity Netcode for GameObjects netcode and it has a problem so that when you are a connected client it doesnt register any cursor and UI interactions (when hovering over the UI element it doesn't get highlighted or when clicked it doesn't do anything)

Comment: Can you please share what you've tried?

Comment: @ErikOverflow the script is just a menu.Setactive(true/false); and it works for the host, im working on a workaround for it, i need to get the area the button covers, how do i get that?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking any object below that GameObject, to not cover that button and to not have Raycast Target on.

Unity, to recognize a click or a hover, permanently calculate a raycast between World Space and your Cursor, so if it hits, and have the Raycast Target on, it will trigger on the first object it hit, ignoring others.

Comment: nothing blocking it, it works well for the host but not for the clients, if you know anything about how to fix that let me know. Im working on a workaround and i need to get the area that the button covers how do i get that

Comment: you can check what's blocking your button by activating Gizmos, the first icon you have on the right side of your Scene View, there's only 2 possibilities, you don't have Raycast Target active, on your button, or there's another element that covers it. Also if you use a Canvas Group, there's a setting that can block Raycast, you can check that too.

Comment: if i use a '            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                Transform objectHit = hit.transform;

                Debug.Log(hit.transform.gameObject.name);
            }' it doesnt log anything when i click around the buttons, i also dont see anything with gizmos

Comment: Can you upload a printscreen, of your button from Inspector, the Scene View with Gizmos On and button selected, also if you have any Canvas or Canvas Group parent ?

Comment: idk if the link works but https://freeimage.host/i/XHWXEb you cant see it but at the time of the screenshot the cursor is hovering over the button with three dots also can you add images directly to the comment?

Comment: I don't think so. I see, can you show us the Scene View and the Inspector of PlayAreaAllwaysOnScreen (which I suppose is Canvas) and CanvasesPlayArea (which i suppose is Canvas Group) ?

Comment: https://freeimage.host/i/XHhzsn , https://freeimage.host/i/XHhAgf the canvasPlayArea is just an empty object

Comment: Everything seems fine, the only reason that your button doesn't work, is a Game Object that covers it. Click there: https://freeimage.host/i/XHhOzP , and find any image that covers your button and disable the Raycast Target if it doesn't supposed to be clicked.

Comment: ok i think i migh have found the problem, i just disabled every object in the scene till it worked an it turned out that the GameController object didnt let it work, then i started to turn off the components and i found that it was the GameController script so ill get back to this in the morning and try to figure out why